# Azure table storage (400) Bad Request

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am using azure table storage, when am trying to query by values, but am getting (400) bad request.not getting this error frequently, but getting few times in a day.

Code is like this.

```
CloudTable table = tableClient.GetTableReference("tablename");
string partitionKey = DateTime.Now.Date.ToLongDateString();
IEnumerable<tableentity> query = (from sms in table.CreateQuery<tableentity>() 
    where sms.PartitionKey == partitionKey 
    && sms.Mobile == mobileNumber && sms.Message == message select sms);
```

Comment: You're setting partition key to the current timestamp. Isn't it possible that you don't have any data on a given day (for example, when the day starts)? FYI (unrelated to your question, unless it's causing a timeout due to excessive data): You're doing a partition scan with every query, searching for matches in the `Mobile` and `Message` properties.

Comment: @DavidMakogon 400 error means the data sent to Table Service is not correct. @Bala ... When you get the error, please check the data that is being sent to Table Service. I am quite sure the data contains some reserved characters which is causing the `$filter` parameter (and hence the querystring) to become invalid.

Comment: @DavidMakogon  Thank you . Let me check with the values which am using to filter.

Comment: Looking into e.RequestInformation.HttpStatusMessage may reveal some useful informtaion

Comment: @BALAG did you resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Setting the **RowKey** property of the **TableEntity** class to a unique ID, like a Guid, has done the trick for me.